# How do I remove all traces of Git for my repository?

Tags: linux, git, unix

I have a repository.  ("git init")

I've done check-ins and commits and logs and stuff.
But, how can I remove all traces of git and delete git off this directory (and subdirectories)?

I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove the `.git` directories inside and you're done.

Comment: Also look for .gitignore files in subdirectories, which are not part of the repository.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
find . -name .git -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: ..and for me, thank you Steve! You can run `git status` afterwards to verify that the directory will not be a git directory afterwards...

Answer (score 4):

I would wildcard that .git

```
find . -name "*.git*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf;
```

Comment: This removes .gitignore. Unless you mean to do that I'd say this is not a recommended approach.

Answer (score -1):

This works well too.

```
find . | grep .git | xargs rm -rf
```